# Как получить данные из get запроса?

Tags: php

Поступает такой запрос https://121.ru/call.php?transaction_id=3751&service_id=16

как в php получить данные transaction_id и service_id?

Comment: ```$transaction_id = $_GET["transaction_id"]```

Comment: Cпасибо большое если хотите можете сделать ответом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметры запроса можно получить, обратившись к cуперглобальному массиву [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
$transaction_id = $_GET["transaction_id"];
$service_id = $_GET["service_id"];
```